# Point class java null pointer exception

Tags: java, pointers, exception, null

```
class Cell {
    Point ob ;
    int distance;
    public Cell(Point x, int i) {
       try {
            ob = x;// works fine
            distance = i;
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());

       }
    }

}

class Cell {
    Point ob ;
    int distance;
    public Cell(Point x, int i) {
        try {
            ob.x = x.x; // throws null pointer exception
            ob.y = x.y;
            distance = i;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }       

    }

}
```

Error: I am getting a null pointer exception in the second code. However when I try to just assign the passed object in constructor, it works fine.

Comment: can you include your code that instantiates `Cell`?

Answer (score 1):

In your first example (which works) you are **assigning** an existing object (passed in by the `Point` parameter `x`) to the `ob` field.

In your second example, you are trying to **access** a property of `ob` in order to assign a value to it, however `ob` never gets assigned to anywhere - it is `null`, hence the exception.

Answer (score 1):

As

```
ob.x = x.x;
```

means getting `x` variable of `ob` object, you first need to create an instance of Point and assign it to ob.

```
ob = new Point();
```

will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You call members on it before you instantiate it.

```
ob = x;// works fine
```

here you just assign the variable, but you don't try to use it.

```
ob.x = x.x; // throws null pointer exception
```

here you try to set the value of a member of `ob`, which is an instance of `Point`. But, you have not yet instantiated the variable, meaning it is, indeed, `null`.

So, either instantiate it first, or try to access the `x` variable of the `x` instance you 've passed as argument.